# solr with autosuggestion linking in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, solr

In my cakephp website , we used the solr search....

Everything working fine now.

I just need to implement one thing now.

In the home page there have a serach box with autosuggestion.

So when we enter a letter or a word it will populate a dropdown with matches rewsult.

That result will taken from solr.

for that i did the following.

In solr schema.xml:

```
<field name="event_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="cat_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="org_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="search_text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
    <copyField source="event_name" dest="search_text" />
    <copyField source="cat_name" dest="search_text" />
    <copyField source="org_name" dest="search_text" />

    <copyField source="multiple_tags" dest="search_text" />
```

Then we are using `search_text` as the seraching condition here.

Now i want to do is, the dorpdown will have `some events name, some organization name, some category name`.

So when i click one of the event name then it will goes to the event page or when i click on the organization name it will go to organization page and so on....

How can i do this?....

This is the dropdown populated after entering a letter.
[image]